# How to read the Address Book as fast as other apps (like Viber, Whatsapp...)

Tags: iphone, ios, client-server, addressbook

I am writing an app where I need to read the Address Book data to search for some contacts of interest, something similar to what many apps do nowadays (like Viber, Whatsapp, Tango...). I need to do matching so I send the data to a server and reply to the client which contacts have the same app installed on their devices.

I have no problem in the logic or mechanism of the idea, my problem is speed! I was able to do what I want but the process took 27 seconds to finish on iPhone4 with 500 contacts on it. On the same device if we try Viber or Whatsapp (or any similar app) the process takes less than 5 seconds.

My method is very straightforward, I do a for loop and read everything. How can I do the same thing but much faster like other apps?

Here is the code that I use:

```
    //variable definitions
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFArrayGetCount(people), people);

    //sort the contents of the Mutable Array
    CFArraySortValues(peopleMutable, CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)), (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName, (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering());

    //read the Address Book
    NSString *fullName, *number;
    ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi;
    int contactID;
    int nameCount=0;//used to count the names in the string to send to server
    NSMutableString *strNamesToSend = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(CFIndex i=0; i< CFArrayGetCount(people); i++)
    {
        record = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
        multi = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        //Contact ID
        contactID = (int)ABRecordGetRecordID(record);

        //Full Name
        fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty), (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
        fullName = [fullName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" (null)" withString:@""];

        //fill data into AddressBook Table
        if(dbOpen == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //pure sqlite3 work to save the names in my app
        }

        //Get multiple numbers from each user (if any)
        for(CFIndex j=0; j<ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); j++)
        {
            number = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, j);

            nameCount++;

            //fill data into AllNumbers Table
            if(dbOpen == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                 //another sqlite3 work to save the numbers
            }
        }

        //send to the server every 29 numbers so we don't send all the 500 numbers at once
        if(nameCount > 29)
        {
            //send to server
        }
```

Comment: Have you profiled it to see where that time is spent? Are you sending the data synchronously to the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried profiling your code at all? A profiler should be able to quickly identify the slow parts of your code.

From a very brief inspection, I notice you're counting the array size at each iteration rather than just once. Move it out of your loop:

```
int count = CFArrayGetCount(people);
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

You don't detail the SQL calls you're making, but the fact you're checking for `SQLITE_OK` implies that you're opening the database each time through the loop. If this is the case you should move this call outside your loop rather than opening the database each time.

I notice that `nameCount` isn't being reset, which means that once it reaches 29, your if case will be hit every single time, causing a huge number of network requests.

Comment: I will try moving the count outside the array and remove the SQLITE_OK issue. The variable nameCount is being reset but to minimize the code posting I omitted this part. It is reset in the last if statement. I don't think I understand what is a profiler. I will update you with the new time consumed in moment, and thanks :)

Comment: By the way, I omitted the database part because it is very basic, but if you feel it is needed I will post it.

Comment: Re. "I don't think I understand what is a profiler", it's one of the most powerful tools Instruments offers. Try one of the many [tutorials](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tech-news/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in) for details. This will show you the slow parts of your code.

Comment: I will try the tutorials and will update you. Again thank you very much.

Comment: Wow that's really a powerful tool. I tried the Time Profiler, although I am new to the profiler stuff but I saw there were 5 or 6 items that were consuming a lot of time and all had the word `sqlite3` in them! It seems what I am doing bad is saving the info in the Documents app folder, and this is now giving my the insight that maybe other apps don't store these info (I am storing the Names and the Numbers of all the contacts in the Address Book). Really @jnic thanks a lot for this tip, it might solve my whole problem :) I will do changes in my program and post the results.

Comment: Yeah it works :D I removed the saving stuff and the process took 2 seconds!!! This means that I have to change the strategy and not save everything (if any) and that solve the case. @jnic you made my day, again thank you very much :D

Comment: Just save the id of the people, you can always look them up with it.

Comment: Yes @timthetoolman I was thinking the same. I tried that but this took 10 seconds to finish while if I keep the id's in the memory (say `NSMutableDictionary`) this takes exactly 1 sec. This leads me to think in 2 solutions: either similar apps store these data in the memory (notice in Viber for example every time you click on All Contacts it takes 1 sec to show), or they start the storing by the moment the app is first launched (when they say "We would like to access your AddressBook"). I will investigate both but I might go to the memory choice which allows live changes of the user contacts.

Comment: @antf: You don't have to save the data synchronously, you could do that async in the background.

Comment: Yes @GeorgFritzsche I agree with you, but saving the data in the background (using another thread) will not deny the fact that it is taking too long, and in the meanwhile if the user clicks on the app AddressBook tab he will see that the data is not ready; while on Viber or Whatsapp this fact does not exist as by the moment the app finishes the start-up wizard you can directly go to the app AddressBook. By the way I am now using a dictionary to store the data live every time the app starts and it is taking 1 sec and I am still updating things... Allow me to thank you as well for your ideas :)

Comment: Thanks you save my lot of time